# Can I have multiple Pis chained together?

Tags: raspbian

In the following question:

[How do I attach two monitors in a dual head configuration?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/657/how-do-i-attach-two-monitors-in-a-dual-head-configuration)

Someone asks how to run two monitors on a Pi, and the answer was to chain 2 Pis together. That made me curious as to what the practical limitations were on chaining Pis together.  Can I do this with 3, 4, etc... Pis?  Is there a limit?

Comment: If you are refering to the approach discussed in the accepted answer over there it would IMO very helpful to describe this directly in your question (to understand without the cross-reference). Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this press release (http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/), it would appear that you can chain at least 20 together into a Lego Supercomputer.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for posting that.  That is really cool..  I suspect it is all managed with a single monitor or VNC connection.  But upvote for coolness.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link. I think it should help it is about how one guy did his http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/

Comment: Websites can go off line or be taken down and as such, to make this a helpful answer you should cite some of the information from the link you give.

Comment: Second that.  It is nice if these Q/As are all self-contained ona single page without requiring a lot of chasing the threads which could be fleshed out into an answer.

Comment: OK, I followed that link and it seems identical to the other answer.  And does not address multiple monitors that I can see.